# Missing styles, Using CardView in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

With CardView as root layout in xml file(for a custom view), i get an error from android studio-
    Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  Failed to find style with id 0x7fff000e in current theme .
I tried choosing different themes for the layout, none worked it seems.
I am using the new appCompatActivity in my app.
any theme works fine with the old ActionBarActivity.

Comment: I just ran into this error.
Have you found a solution?

Comment: selecting android M did the job.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the elements below to the AppTheme helped me to solve a similar problem

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is a bit ate for your question but just in case someone needs it:

Mine was solved after restarting android studio using the below option:

> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8sp">
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

check out here https://codingtemplates.com/how-to-make-cardview-in-android-studio